# Why does Qt not work with dll injection?

Tags: qt, dll, unicode, hook, multibyte

I am currently working on a program that extract text messages from a third party program, so I dont have to enter tooltip text manually in my excel sheets. I am using dll injection for this and have already successfully hooked the microsoft's textoutw function. The program also gives me the messages I want. So the hook was successful.

Now, I want to put some "cloths" (a GUI) on my program and have decided to go with Qt. So I designed a GUI and have put my dll engine into the GUI.

After I have done this, I tried out my program, but now the program does not hook anymore. The dll hook code and everything else are exactly the same, except they are in a qt environment now.

I suspected an unicode/multibyte problem, but after I have set my original "non-qt" code to unicode and reinserted that piece of code into the Qt project, I still does not work.

I have done some research in the internet, an interesting source said that I have to use qwidget::winId, however I have tried this and still nothing works.

There is no error message, no console output whatsoever...

I am kinda stuck at this problem for hours now... hope you guys can help me!

Jonathan

Comment: What do you want to hook? Qt doesn't use native windows controls.

Comment: The most important missing piece of information is: are you trying to hook a Qt program, or are you using Qt as a GUI for the string extraction? The latter shouldn't change anything, the former won't work since Qt doesn't use the functions that you're trying to hook. You'd need to read Qt's source code to figure out what can be hooked instead.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the response! I am actually trying to hook a non-Qt program with my code being implemented in a Qt environment. You have an idea?

Comment: You need to show some code that demonstrates the problem.